# How retrieve row position for azure mobile services tables

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

Im using Azure Mobile Services (in a HTML client) for a simple Score Wall application.

First the app take the top 100 scores

```
client.getTable("ScoreWall").orderBy("score").take(100).read().then(...
```

and later show the current user position

```
client.getTable("ScoreWall").where({"userId":uid}).select("userId","score").read().then(...
```

but I would like to retrieve the current user position in world rank.. I didn't found any documentation for select like:

```
select("row_position","userId","score")
```

How can I retrieve this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't think of a good way to do this all in the query, but given a dataset of only 100, there isn't any significant impact to doing some post processing. Here's what I cooked up (I've got it in a js backend, since I had one laying around to try).

```
function returnAll(req, res) {
    var todoTable = req.service.tables.getTable('todoitem');
    var n = 1;
    var q = todoTable.select(function () {
        var obj = { num: n, text: this.text };
        n++;
        return obj;
    }).orderBy("text").take(100);

    q.read({
        success: function (results) {
            var Sarah = {};
            results.forEach(function (item) { if (item.text === "Sarah") { Sarah = item } });
            res.send(200, { "results": results, "sarah": Sarah });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            res.send(500, err);
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously, kind of a silly demo but it gets the point across. Here's the result:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "num": 1,
            "text": "Angela"
        },
        {
            "num": 2,
            "text": "Chris"
        },
        {
            "num": 3,
            "text": "John"
        },
        {
            "num": 4,
            "text": "Nikesh"
        },
        {
            "num": 5,
            "text": "Sarah"
        }
    ],
    "sarah": {
        "num": 5,
        "text": "Sarah"
    }
}
```

There's a couple of things to be concerned with in my example if you were to scale it up to millions of rows (but I'd probably go with a separate job that calculated top 100 and dumped it into table or tagged the user object with rank on a periodic basis to solve that scale), but for a 100, it's decent.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. But I dont have only 100 data. The app shows the first 100 . and the user position, it can be more than 100th position, like 9999th..

Comment: In that regard, definitely consider a scheduled job which updates user rank. If you don't care about 100% accuracy and you wanted to minimize your load, you could have a job run ever 5 minutes or so which processed 1000 records at a time the user rank.

Comment: The reason for batching is that you'll be doing a lot of db inserts - it's best to spread it out as databases are frequently io bound.